# Came across a 'params.store' line -- is there any difference/benefit over params[:key]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Coworker came across a line of code that referenced `params.store 'keyname', value`, which appears to do the same thing as `params[:keyname] = value`.

Neither of us have seen the first syntax. Is there any difference with how this is evaluated? Google is unhelpfully not honoring my searches using `"params.store"` (returning bolded results referencing `params[:store]`), so I haven't been able to find anything on using `:store` over the hash syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `store` equal to `[]=`. Just check description of these methods and source code [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Hash/store).

**UPDATE**:
[Here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/adfeb95c87b31e17c7e1d78d65f9b548f26ccfed/hash.c#L3985-L3986) is place is Ruby sources which show that the `store` equal to `[]=`.